# PhoneGap 3.x / iOs6 iOs7 / AngularJs - Plugin objects aren't available with custom www/index.html location

Tags: ios, angularjs, plugins, cordova

**How do I gain access to the javascript plugin objects and use a custom www/index.html location?**

When I add this line into **project_name/www/config.xml**:

```
<content src="app/index.html" />
```

I am able to load a custom location for the www/index.html but I do not have access to any of the Cordova Plugins that are installed.

The following code reports success when the default www/index.html is loaded.

When the index.html is loaded from www/app/index.html, navigator.connection is undefined, and an error is thrown:

```
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.connection.type')
```

Here is the code that initializes phonegap, waits for the device to be ready, initializes angularJS, and then checks the connection through the plugin.

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
        checkConnection();
    },
}
app.initialize();

function checkConnection() {
    alert('Reporting connection information');
    try{
        alert(navigator.connection.type);
    } catch(error) {
        alert('Error' + error);
        alert(navigator);
    }
}
```

Additional information:

- This behavior is consistent with PhoneGap 3.0 and 3.1
- The native plugin files do exist in the project_name/platforms/ios/Plugins directory (ie: CDVConnection.m & CDVConnection.h)
- I'm using AngularJS 1.2
- Tested with iOs6, iOs7
- XCode 5.0 and 5.2
- With Phonegap 3.1, the XCode log reports "*2013-11-12 13:39:14.179 ESA Mobile[936:60b] Unlimited access to network resources*". Indicating the plugins are loaded in native code and that I just don't have access to the javascript objects.

Comment: Post your index.html where the `cordova_plugins.js` is included

Comment: What do you  mean by post? cordova_plugins.js is in www/cordova_plugins.js

Comment: I want you to add code from your index.html... So in your index.html, you have `<script src="cordova_plugins.js">` or `<script src="../cordova_plugins.js">`?

Comment: cordova_plugins.js is supposedly included inside www/phonegap.js and shouldn't have to be included specifically, although that's a good direction for troubleshooting. I resolved the problem with [the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19941243/1669961). I haven't dug into the why behind it. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the file **www/app/index.html**

do not use:

```
<script src="../phonegap.js"></script>
```

Instead, **using the cordova file resolved the problem**:

```
<script src="../cordova.js"></script>
```

**Note:** I verified this with phonegap 3.1 and cordova 3.1. I did not regression test it for 3.0.

Comment: Hi Brian, yes, I have checked it. Actually I am using login with Facebook, and in that, I have import cordova.js instead of phonegap.js. And it is working well. But there is one issue...I am also using social plugin into that project. Which is working with Phonegap.js. So, when I am comment phonegap.js, and import cordova.js, then social plugin not working. and Facebook working. While in reverse, facebook not working, social plugin working. So have you any idea regarding this?